# Ubuntu doesn't boot when Mount bind not available during startup

Tags: 16.04, boot, fstab, mate, bind

My /etc/fstab looks like this:

```
...
/mnt/FP5/daten/bilder/2002/ /home/johkra/Bilder/2002 none bind
...
```

How can I configure my fstab that Ubuntu does not wait for the bind.
Can ubuntu mount it when it is actually needed?

Thanks and have a good 2018!

Comment: Is that the complete line in `/etc/fstab`? You are missing the fifth and sixth field. Try to add `0 0` at the end of your line if it is missing and try again.

Comment: @Thomas  0  0 is unnecessary with mount bind. @johkra you can try adding the noauto option `/mnt/FP5/daten/bilder/2002/ /home/johkra/Bilder/2002 noauto bind` .

Comment: The option `-nofail`would be enough to overcome the wait problem. Thus the mount still will be done when the device is available. To have a device mounted when itis _needed_, there are ways like `autofs` or maybe `systemd.mount` or `systemd.automount` - I am not familiar to the latter two, so don'tknow if that works.

Comment: Now I changed the line to
/mnt/FP5/daten/bilder/2002/ /home/johkra/Bilder/2002 noauto,nofail bind

But still no solution. I was very confident that the nofail-option should'veworked.

Comment: Looks like you will have to use something other than mount bind. You could write a script if .... mount ... and call it from rc.local or perhaps use link rather than bind.

Comment: There are some hints on https://ddumont.wordpress.com/2016/04/24/automount-usb-devices-with-systemd/. Did not get it to run this way with `bind`, but will come back when I succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally succeeded, but before some caveats:

- do not add the option `x-systemd.automount` to (partitions on) devices that are needed for any services (like NFS), when possibly the drive is not connected at boot
- do avoid using `x-systemd.automount` together with other automounters (like autofs).

Now for the solution:

I have an external disk with an xfs filesystem on it (labelled `data`) which should be mounted to `/data` when connected. The `fstab` entry reads

```
LABEL=data /data    xfs nofail,auto,noatime 0   0
```

`nofail` leads to not interrupting the boot process when the disk is not connected, and `auto` says to mount the disk as soon as it is connected (this is different from the old `init` behavior, which did only mount at boot time).

Now, to `bind` mount `/data` to my `/home/ridgy/data` when I needed that, I added the line

```
/data           /home/ridgy/data none bind,nofail,noauto,x-systemd.automount,noatime
```

Then, after connecting the disk the partition was connected automatically and `mount` showed

```
/dev/sda1 on /data type xfs (rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

But there still was no mount on `/home/ridgy/data`. But `ls data` now listed the content of `/data`, and `mount` additionally had

```
/dev/sda1 on /home/ridgy/data type xfs (rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

what was the result I wanted.

Hard removing the USB disk unmounted both mounts on that partition; but listing ~/data now let the command hang. I did not experiment with different values for any sort of timeout; maybe this could help in this case.